# Has the trainval.txt in the VOC2012 the same purpose like the test.txt in the VOC2007?

Tags: dataset, deep-learning

When I downloaded the VOC2012 dataset and the VOC2007 dataset for a project, the project throws an error telling me the following:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'VOCdevkit/VOC2007/ImageSets/Main/trainval.txt'
>
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'VOCdevkit/VOC2012/ImageSets/Main/test.txt'

In VOC2007 test.txt is available, trainval.txt is not. In VOC2012 it is vice versa.

So what is the purpose of this two files and why they are not available in one of the datasets?

I downloaded them from:

http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2012/VOCtrainval_11-May-2012.tar and
http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2007/VOCtrainval_06-Nov-2007.tar

Answer (score 1):

You can download VOC 2012 test from the evaluation server:
http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk:8080/

The file VOCdevkit/VOC2007/ImageSets/Main/trainval.txt appears in our pascal07 distribution. I do not know why you do not have it.